# How do I get a different parser to work on content identified by nestedExpr in pyparsing

Tags: python-2.7, pyparsing

I have a nested block of text that is not necessarily well formatted (indented) which needs to be parsed and operated on further.

A sample of the text:

```
cell(hi) {
    param1 : true;
    param2 : false;
    func1() {
     param3 : hello;
        param4 : hi;
    }
    func2() {
    param5 : 10;
    nestedFunc1() {
        nestedParam6 : 20;
       nestedFunc2(args) {
        index1(a,b,c,d,e);
        values(1,2,3,4,\
               5);
       }
    }
    }
}
```

The above snippet is a sample of the text I intend to parse.

So far, here is the parser I have come up with:

```
Group(Word("cell") + QuotedString('(', escChar=None, endQuoteChar=')') + nestedExpr(opener='{', closer='}').setResultsName("cell")
```

I tried using the `content=LineEnd()` argument for the `nestedExpr` call but that does not get me what I expect.

Apart from that, I have a few other parsers for the content inside the `cell {...}` wrapper. Examples:

```
params          = Group(Regex(r'(.*)\s*:\s*(.*);')).setResultsName("params")
LookupTables    = Group(Word(k) + QuotedString('(', escChar=None, endQuoteChar=')') + QuotedString("{", multiline=True, endQuoteChar="}") )
```

I was wondering if there is an efficient way to parse the nested block and obtain the output in the following format:

```
[
    ['cell', 'hi']
    {'param1': 'true'}
    {'param2': 'false'}
    ['func1'
        {'param3': 'hello'}
        {'param4': 'hi'}
    ]
    ['func2'
        {'param5': '10'}
        ['nestedFunc1'
            {'index1(a,b,c,d,e)': None}
            {'values(1,2,3,4,5)': None}
        ]
    ]
]
```

Basically, I am trying to obtain the Look-up Tables inside of the data:

```
index1(a) = 1
index1(b) = 2
index1(c) = 3
index1(d) = 4
index1(e) = 5
```

When I try to use `nestedExpr` on my input text, I obtain a nested list of all content separated by spaces without the new line characters (shown below). I will at the very least need the new line characters so that I can join the output and re-create the original nested block of data to apply my own parsers using `setParseAction` etc.

Here is the output I obtain currently:

```
Parser:
tp      = Group(Word("cell") + QuotedString('(', escChar=None, endQuoteChar=')') + nestedExpr(opener='{', closer='}') ).setResultsName("cell")

Output:
[['cell', 'hi', ['param1', ':', 'true;', 'param2', ':', 'false;', 'func1()', ['param3', ':', 'hello;', 'param4', ':', 'hi;'], 'func2()', ['param5', ':', '10;', 'nestedFunc1()', ['nestedParam6', ':', '20;', 'nestedFunc2(args)', ['index1(a,b,c,d,e);', 'values(1,2,3,4,\\', '5);']]]]]]
```

Comment: Try solving this without using `nestedExpr`. That is, do an explicit recursive parser using `pp.Forward`. `nestedExpr` is a shortcut I wrote primarily for text of the form "here is a bunch of stuff that I don't care to parse out in detail, but it is enclosed in nested delimiters so I can't just use SkipTo". Since you *do* want to parse the contents, then probably just bite the bullet and parse them. You could also try using `searchString` instead of `parseString`, and just search for the patterns of interest and ignore everything else.

Comment: @PaulMcG Yes, I agree that I do care about the content inside. I was also wondering if there is anyway I can leverage the simple functionality of `nestedExpr` to obtain the entire block of text captured with no formatting (i.e. content is not split into a list based on white-space). That way, I can go ahead and write my parser for the content inside of the main nested block (`cell(hi) { ... }` in this case).

Comment: Wrap the `nestedExpr` with `originalTextFor` and you'll get back the contents as the original string, complete with all whitespace and newlines.